# Delete few row starting at a specific ID

Tags: sql

How can I delete row starting at RS_ID=2542 until the end, while RS_NOM = salutation 2 using SQL ?

[image: bdd]

In this example I need to delete all my row with RS_NOM = salutation 2 BUT only start the delete at row where RS_ID=2542.

So the line where RS_ID = 2541 will remain.

Any help ?

Comment: delete from yourtable where rs_id>2541 and rs_nom="salutation 2" ?

Comment: @ergonaut, single quotes for string literals, double are for column names.

Comment: @jarlh you are correct.

Comment: Delete from tablename where id>your id

Comment: I totaly forgot that i can use < and > .. i used a while.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Delete from TABLE_NAME where RS_ID >= 2542
                    and RS_NOM='Salutation 2'`

That could have been googled though

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from tablename where id>your id
```